# How to add a vendor prefix to a Tailwind CSS value and not the property?

Tags: tailwind-css, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to use `text-align: center` (Tailwind class, `text-center`) but would like to apply a vendor prefix to the value so it would be, `text-align: -webkit-center`. How can I apply it inline?

I've tried `text-[-webkit-center]` but it is interpreted as `color: -webkit-center`, which is incorrect.

I understand that [Tailwind has an Autoprefixer option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support#vendor-prefixes), but that applies the prefix to the property (ie. `-webkit-box-align: center`) and not the value.

Comment: `text-align: -webkit-center` is a block alignment value. More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary value syntax only works for class utilities registered with `matchUtilities()` internally, where their values can be ["dynamic"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities). For the class utilities for `text-align`, [they are registered in Tailwind core via `addUtilities()`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/8350cffdad34efb6625e0f2b0ff738edaf0d1cce/src/corePlugins.js#L2002-L2011), since there are only a few valid values `text-align` can have:

```js
textAlign: ({ addUtilities }) => {
  addUtilities({
    '.text-left': { 'text-align': 'left' },
    '.text-center': { 'text-align': 'center' },
    '.text-right': { 'text-align': 'right' },
    '.text-justify': { 'text-align': 'justify' },
    '.text-start': { 'text-align': 'start' },
    '.text-end': { 'text-align': 'end' },
  })
},
```

Thus they are more "static". To apply `text-align: -webkit-center`, you could:

- Use an [arbitrary property class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties) like:

  ```html
  <div class="[text-align:-webkit-center]">
  ```
- Use a [Tailwind Plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-utilities) that adds a rule that applies the declaration:

  ```js
  const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

  module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      plugin(function({ addUtilities }) {
        addUtilities({
          '.text-webkit-center': {
            'text-align': '-webkit-center',
          },
        })
      })
    ]
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="text-webkit-center">
  ```
- Add a CSS rule to a CSS file (or otherwise) that loads on to the page:

  ```css
  .text-webkit-center {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="text-webkit-center">
  ```